# Удаление своих сообщений VK (для всех) через Api VK?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как можно удалить свои сообщения для всех в определенной беседе через API

Определенный код (скрипт), с вставкой ID беседы и вставкой своей ID страницы, по которому будут удаляться сообщения для всех. 
Через API VK я могу удалить 1 сообщение (если знаешь ID)
1) Как мне узнать ID всех своих сообщений отправленных в беседу (за 24 часа офк)
2) И как одним кодом можно очистить их все

Answer (score 3):

Удалить своё сообщение, можно методом [`messages.delete`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.delete), указав параметр `delete_for_all = True`
Получить свои отправленные сообщения в беседу, можно методом [`messages.getHistory`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getHistory), запустив его в цикле, попутно сверяя дату сообщения и id пользователя со своим.

Comment: Это всё пройденная история, как можно всё быстрее это выполнить?

Comment: Ну, Вам подсказали - в цикле через messages.getHistory находите все свои сообщение за Н время, и так же циклом делаете удаление.